# Deployment of ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, deployment, installation

I am starting to write an open source application which is intended to be deployed on premises with MS SQL Server as backend. Now I was wondering how to go about deploying the application and the SQL Server backend.

For MSSQL there is a pretty clear installation path but I was wondering how I could create an easy installer for the web application. The idea is to copy the website to some location, start it and then call a special installation controller where the user could specify a database user with elevated privileges (such as the 'sa' user). The website should then create some database users, views and tables on that database and perform the initial setup. Additionally, it should also modify the configuration of the website to use the correct database user.

Of course, other ideas are welcome as well. How do you handle the deployment of a website for a small company which doesn't have dedicated IT staff.

Comment: What platform are you planning to host it on? Windows Server? A Linux flavor?

Comment: The intention is to host it on Windows, it's most likely to be deployed together with the SQL Server.